# I have intents enabled, but the on_member_update function still doesn't give me the role

Tags: discord.py

Basically the bot is supposed to give you the "Cool role" role if your status is "cool" But for some reason, it doesn't and it also doesn't give me any errors. Also, it doesn't seem like the event triggers at all.

```py
# Token, Client
intents = discord.Intents().all()  # Turn on intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.',
                      intents=intents)  # initialize client

# Gives role if you have status
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    # get differences in before and after activities
    differences = set(before.activities) ^ set(after.activities)
    # If differences is none, return
    if len(differences) == 0:
        return
    # utils.get the differences and look for the custom activity type with the name
    activity = discord.utils.get(differences, name="Cool")
    # if activity is None, return
    if activity is None:
        return
    # if activity in before.activities, remove the role
    role = after.guild.get_role("Cool role")
    if activity in before.activities:
        await after.remove_roles(role)
        # else add the role
    else:
        await after.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve], emphasis on **minimal**. As well, have you turned on intents in the dev portal?

Comment: I edited it, and yes, intents are on in the dev portal.

Comment: So is the problem that `on_member_update` doesn't run?

Comment: yeah it doesnt run or atleast it doesn't trigger

Answer (score 1):

`member_update` event is no longer dispatched when a member's status or activity updates. There is `presence_update` instead.
You also need the `presences` intent as well as the `members` intent enabled.

```py
@client.event
async def on_presence_update(before, after):
    pass
```

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_presence_update#discord.on_presence_update)